# pyqtgraph doesn't show the entire data

Tags: python, pyside, pyaudio, pyqtgraph

I'm running a python program to real-time-plot voice.
I'm basically following the general tutorial, but it doesn't get plotted properly.
Env: python2.7, pyside+pyqtgraph, windows10, anaconda venv

my code is as below:

```
# coding:utf-8

import numpy as np
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

import pyaudio

sample_rate = 16000
frame_length = 1024
frame_shift = 80


class PlotWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self.win.setWindowTitle("realtime plotting")
        self.win.resize(1100, 400)
        self.plt = self.win.addPlot(title="updating_plot")  
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        #self.ymin = -1000
        #self.ymax = 1000
        self.plt.setYRange(-1.0, 1.0)  
        self.curve = self.plt.plot(pen='y')  

        self.CHUNK = frame_length  
        self.RATE = sample_rate  
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                      channels=1,
                                      rate=self.RATE,
                                      input=True,
                                      output=True,
                                      frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)



        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(5) 

        self.data = np.zeros(self.CHUNK)

    def update(self):
        self.data = self.AudioInput()
        self.curve.setData(self.data)


    def AudioInput(self):
        ret = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)
        ret = np.frombuffer(ret, dtype="int16") / 32768
        numpydata = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)
        numpydata = np.fromstring(numpydata, dtype=np.int16)
        #print("RET", ret)
        #print("NUMPYDATA", numpydata)
        return numpydata


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plotwin = PlotWindow()

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

and the plotted image is like this.
It seems like the top is trimmed somehow and doesn't show the entire data.

plot image

[image]

Even when I do with a super simple version of code, it behaves the same way.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
pg.plot(data)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

plot image

[image]

Comment: `self.plt.setYRange(-1.0, 10)`  ?

Comment: sorry it's supposed to be ```self.plt.setYRange(-1.0, 1.0) ```. I fixed it.

Comment: Please create a minimum example that everybody can run. Don't use pyaudio, use some random numbers.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for your advice, I added a simple code and outcome. hope someone could get me any advice though...

Answer (score 0):

Please try exactly this code.

```
import sys

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
data = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
pg.plot(data)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

On my machine (Linux, Python 3.6, pyqtgraph 0.10.0) this looks perfectly fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the exact same image as what I put in my question came out... is it something about configs of pyqtgraph or something?

Comment: >On my machine (Linux, Python 3.6, pyqtgraph 0.10.0) this looks perfectly fine: maybe it's because of my python2.7??